# Get the words after specific character PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i want to get words after specific character in pl/sql

for example :

text = '2 - 99 - 7051B'

I want to see *7051B* which means after second '-' to the last character.

```
function try ( text in varchar2 )
is begin
 v_textout varchar2(100) := '';
 --some process
 return v_textout;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
select substr(text , instr(text , '-', 1, 2) + 1, length(text))
      from dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for PL/SQL to extract the desired part. Two alternative methods use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` regular expression functions respectively

```
WITH t(text) AS
(
 SELECT '2 - 99 - 7051B' FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(text,'(.*- )(\S+)','\2') AS first_method,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(text,'[^- ]+$') AS second_method
  FROM t;

FIRST_METHOD    SECOND_METHOD
------------    -------------
7051B           7051B
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d14b01fd6a422e457c64eb5919a56347)</kbd>

where the spaces after dash characters are left deliberately according to the sample, and plus(`+`) stands for *one or more occurences for the match* .